# SQL syntax error check right syntax on mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM nyheder ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2' at line 1

found the place where it was i dont no why it dont work
nyheder ( meaning news )

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Nyheder</h2>
    <div class="row">

    <?php
$html = '';
$page = '';
$id = '';
$news_pr_page = 5;
$current_page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['pagenr']) && is_int($_GET['pagenr'] * 1)){
    $page = $_GET['pagenr'];
    $current_page = ($_GET['pagenr'] * 1);
}
$sql ="SELECT COUNT(ID) AS antal FROM nyheder";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $products = $row['antal'];
   //exit($products);
   //echo ($prody);
  // $total_pages = ceil($products / $news_pr_page);
   //exit($total_pages);
   $offset = ($current_page - 1) * $news_pr_page;


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM nyheder
   ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $news_pr_page OFFSET $offset";

    $arr = getData($sql, $conn);
    foreach($arr as $value){
        $html .= '
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="mt-4 nyheder white">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">'.$value['overskrift'].'</h3>
                    <p>'.$value['oprettelsesdato'].'</p>
                    <p>'. substr($value['tekst'], 0, 182) . '...</p>
                    <a href="?page=nyhedSingle&id=' . $value['ID'] . '"><button>Læs mere</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            ';
}

   $html .= '</ul>
   </div>
</div>';
$html .='<ul class="pagination">';
        if($page > 1 && $page !== 1)
        {
            $href = '?page=nyheder&id='.$id.'&pagenr='.($current_page > 1 ? $current_page-1 : 1).'';
            $html .= '<li><a href="'.$href.'">Tidligere nyheder</a></li>';
        }
        if($products >= $news_pr_page)
        {
            $href = '?page=nyheder&id='.$id.'&pagenr='.($current_page+1).'';
            $html .= '<li><a href="'.$href.'">Ældre nyheder</a></li>';
        }

return $html;
?>
```

found also this, hope this help i am not used to stackoverflow how can i explain better my english bad sorry

```
<a href="../?page=nyheder">Tilbage</a>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$html = '';
//Min SQL-sætning til hentning af data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nyheder

        WHERE nyheder.ID = " . $id . "
        ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1";

$arr = getData($sql, $conn);
if(is_array($arr)){
    foreach($arr as $value){
        $html .= '
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="mt-4 nyhederSingle white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">'.$value['overskrift'].'</h3>
                <p>'.$value['oprettelsesdato'].'</p>
                <p>'.$value['tekst'].'</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        ';
    }
}

return $html;

?>
```

Comment: There appears to be no query ending with `ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2` in the code you have shown.

Comment: Watch out for [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: well i dont no where that part exactly come from it dont tell me

dont think i even have that in my script

Comment: Well, it's your code, how should we know?

Comment: @DenizBircan, it is part of your code, you wrote it!. Search in the php source file for the string "ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2" and see where that query is!

Comment: You need to go through all your code and find where that SQL statement is made. It's literally _impossible_ for us to be able to help if we can't see the actual query. This is a bit like going to a car mechanic, asking them to look at your friends car to find out what's wrong with yours.

Comment: This is a new level of unbelievableness.

Comment: Also, you are _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks. _Never_ use user data ($_GET, $_POST etc) directly in your queries. I would recommend that you look up how to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: found out how to edit hmm it says asc?

Comment: @DenizBircan there is an edit button to edit your question

Answer (score 0):

sorry about all this found problem

$sql = "SELECT nyheder.* FROM nyheder ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2";

it was on line 67.

```
<?php
$sql = " SELECT * FROM omklubben ";
$arr = getData($sql, $conn);
foreach($arr as $value){
$html = '
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="mt-4 omKlubben white">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">'. $value['headline'] .'</h3>
                    <p>'. $value['text'] .'</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="mt-4 white">
                <div class="card-body brugteKajakkerForside">
                    <h3 class="card-title" style="color:black;">Brugte kajakker</h3>
                    <div class="row">';
}

                        $sql = "
                        SELECT kajakker.model, kajakker.pris,
                        kajak_billede.billednavn

                        FROM kajakker 

                        INNER JOIN kajak_billede 
                        ON kajak_billede.fk_kajak = kajakker.ID 

                        ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3";

                        $arr = getData($sql, $conn);
                        foreach($arr as $value){
                            $html .= '
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <img src="images/' . $value['billednavn'] . '" alt="' . $value['billednavn'] . '">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="priser" style="width:100%; background-color:#95cce8;">
                                            <p>'. $value['model'] .'</p>
                                            <p>'. $value['pris'] .' kr.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ';
                        }
                    $html .= '
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="nyhederForside col-md-12">
                <form action="" method="get">
                    <center>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="soegning">
                    <input type="search" name="fritekst" placeholder="Søg">
                    </center>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="list-group">
                <div class="nyhederForside white col-md-12">
                    <img src="../images/img02.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">

                    <h3>Nyheder</h3>';

                    $sql = "SELECT nyheder * FROM nyheder ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2";
                    $arr = getData($sql, $conn);
                    foreach($arr as $value){
                    $html .= '<p>' . showDateSmall($value['oprettelsesdato']) . ' ' . $value['overskrift'] . '</p>';
                    }

                    $html .= '
                    <center><a href="?page=nyheder"><button style="cursor:pointer;">Nyheder >></button></a></center>
                </div>

                 <div class="nyhederForside white col-md-12" style="margin-top:30px;">
                    <img src="../images/img01.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    <h3>2018</h3>
                    <p>Marts</p>';

                    $sql = "SELECT bgv_info.* FROM bgv_info ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2";
                    $arr = getData($sql, $conn);
                    foreach($arr as $value){
                    $html .= '<p>' . showDateSmall($value['oprettelsesdato']) . ' ' . $value['bgv_navn'] . '</p>';
                    }
                    $html .= '
                    <center><a href="?page=arrangementer"><button style="cursor:pointer;">Kalender >></button></a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';

return $html;
?>
```